# Most overtime games for a team during a season

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

With the Browns just finishing their third overtime game this season (in week 5), does anybody know what is the most overtime games played by a single team during a season?

[This page](https://sportsdelve.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/a-complete-record-of-nfl-overtime/) seems to have a lot of data on overtime, but seems to miss this particular stat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Green Bay Packers were involved in [5 overtime games in 1983](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/tgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=game&year_min=1983&year_max=1983&game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&temperature_gtlt=lt&overtime=Y&c5val=1.0&order_by=game_date&team_id=gnb).

Using Pro Football Reference's Team Game Finder, the following [query](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/tgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=season&year_min=1940&year_max=2018&game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&temperature_gtlt=lt&overtime=Y&c5val=1.0&order_by=game_date) I used was: "In a single season, from 1940 to 2018, in the Regular Season, game went to overtime, sorted by most games in season matching criteria."

Answer (score -2):

Raiders with 4 [in 2021/22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Las_Vegas_Raiders_season)   The last one was against the Los Angeles chargers.  Winner advanced to the playoffs

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. Please provide a source to your answer

Comment: Given the existing answer has a team with 5 OT games, being more than 4, I cannot see how this is correct in any way.